# How to design Restful service request when there is multiple subclasses?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, oop, design-patterns

I have got 2 end points which are

- http://localhost:8080/account/v1/credit/{accountNumber} (POST -> TransactionDTO)
- http://localhost:8080/account/v1/debit/{accountNumber}  (POST -> TransactionDTO)

And my TransactionDTO:

```
public class TransactionDTO {

    @NotNull
    private Double amount;

    public TransactionDTO(@NotNull Double amount) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
    }
... Getters Setters
}
```

Basically,  when credit is called, the amount of dto is added to the account's balance associated with the given accountNumber, so far no problem.

However, when debit is called, as you can see below, there are multiple withdraw transaction types(and more withdraw transaction types can be added as the app gets bigger) such as BillPaymentTransaction, WithdrawTransaction.

**My problem is  how should I design the request class(TransactionDTO) so that when it comes to the controller I can understand which type of withdraw transaction came and do the specific action for it.**

My controller's methods:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/credit/{accountNumber}")
public ResponseEntity<TransactionStatus> credit(@PathVariable String accountNumber, @RequestBody TransactionDTO depositTransaction) throws InsufficientBalanceException {
    TransactionStatus response = accountService.credit(accountNumber, depositTransaction);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PostMapping(path = "/debit/{accountNumber}")
public ResponseEntity<TransactionStatus> debit(@PathVariable String accountNumber, @RequestBody TransactionDTO withdrawalTransaction) throws InsufficientBalanceException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(accountService.debit(accountNumber, withdrawalTransaction),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

[image: Transaction Architecture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want/need to have just one endpoint for multiple types of withdrawals, you could have an Enum defining the different types and add that as a field to the TransactionDTO.

Something like this:

```
public enum DebitType { BILL_PAYMENT, WITHDRAW, ... }

public class DebitTransactionDTO {

    @NotNull
    private Double amount;

    @NotNull
    private DebitType debitType;

    public DebitTransactionDTO(@NotNull Double amount, @NotNull DebitType debitType) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.debitType = debitType;
    }
    ... Getters Setters
}
```

Since you probably do not want to have the debit type in the credit transaction, you might want to have separate DTO classes for credit and debit (hence the DebitTransactionDTO class name).

Comment: I got you. One more question here, is it good to use factory pattern to get debitType as input and return a created object of it in service layer ?

Comment: Yes, that would make a lot of sense.